# What is the recommended way to filter Objects with Unique property in the array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to filter objects in array based on unique property
here i have an array where KEY is the key value in the objects.
How to filter the objects where key value is unique. Key value is repeated in the objects but should only the first one should be filtered out.

```
var array = [];
array = [
  {
    "KEY": "00001",
    "ID": "1234",
    "ID_DESC": "1234",
    "NOT_UNIQUE_VALUE": "119.0",
    "NOT_UNIQUE_TYPE": "this is not unique"
  }, 
  {
    "KEY":"00001",
    "ID":"1234",
    "ID_DESC":"1234",
    "NOT_UNIQUE_VALUE":"11019.0",
    "NOT_UNIQUE_TYPE":"not unique type"
  },
  {
    "KEY":"00002",
    "ID":"2468",
    "ID_DESC":"2468",
    "NOT_UNIQUE_VALUE":"195.0",
    "NOT_UNIQUE_TYPE":"not unique type",
  },
  {
    "KEY":"00002",
    "ID":"2468",
    "ID_DESC":"2468",
    "NOT_UNIQUE_VALUE":"195.0",
    "NOT_UNIQUE_TYPE":"not unique type",
  }]
```

Result:

```
uniquearray = [
  {
    "KEY":"00001",
    "ID":"1234",
    "ID_DESC":"1234",
    "NOT_UNIQUE_VALUE":"119.0",
    "NO T_UNIQUE_TYPE":"this is not unique"
  },
  {
    "KEY":"00002",
    "ID":"2468",
    "ID_DESC":"2468",
    "NOT_UNIQUE_VALUE":"195.0",
    "NOT_UNIQUE_TYPE":"not unique type"
  }]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did it go wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var uniqueArray = []
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var uniquevalue = array[i];
    unique[array.KEY] = uniquevalue;
}
for (var name in unique) {
    var uniqueObject = unique[name];
    uniqueArray.push(uniqueObject);
}
```

Comment: From the top of my head I would say this snippet produces the last duplicate, resulting in the `11019.0`-thing, not the `119.0` (for `"KEY":"00001"`)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the members and look at the KEY property. If it's not been seen before, add it to a list of seen keys and return true. If it has been seen before, return false. E.g.

```js
var array = [{
  "KEY": "00001",
  "ID": "1234",
  "ID_DESC": "1234",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_VALUE": "119.0",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_TYPE": "this is not unique"
}, {
  "KEY": "00001",
  "ID": "1234",
  "ID_DESC": "1234",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_VALUE": "11019.0",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_TYPE": "not unique type"
}, {
  "KEY": "00002",
  "ID": "2468",
  "ID_DESC": "2468",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_VALUE": "195.0",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_TYPE": "not unique type",
}, {
  "KEY": "00002",
  "ID": "2468",
  "ID_DESC": "2468",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_VALUE": "195.0",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_TYPE": "not unique type",
}]

var seenKeys = Object.create(null);
var result = array.filter(function(obj) {
  return seenKeys[obj.KEY]? false : seenKeys[obj.KEY] = true;
});

console.log(result)
```

As an arrow function:

```
var seenKeys = Object.create(null);
var result = array.filter(obj => seenKeys[obj.KEY]? false : seenKeys[obj.KEY] = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `reduce()`, collecting unique elements into a `Map` (it even preserves insertion order, if that is expected), and packing it back to an array at the end:

```js
var array = [{
  "KEY": "00001",
  "ID": "1234",
  "ID_DESC": "1234",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_VALUE": "119.0",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_TYPE": "this is not unique"
}, {
  "KEY": "00001",
  "ID": "1234",
  "ID_DESC": "1234",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_VALUE": "11019.0",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_TYPE": "not unique type"
}, {
  "KEY": "00002",
  "ID": "2468",
  "ID_DESC": "2468",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_VALUE": "195.0",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_TYPE": "not unique type",
}, {
  "KEY": "00002",
  "ID": "2468",
  "ID_DESC": "2468",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_VALUE": "195.0",
  "NOT_UNIQUE_TYPE": "not unique type",
}]

var result = Array.from(array.reduce((m,o) => {
  if(!m.has(o.KEY))
    m.set(o.KEY, o);
  return m;
}, new Map()).values());

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ES6 version filter utility:

```
// Unique is only that item, if we find him in array on the same index.
const onlyUniqueProperty = prop => (value, index, self) =>
    self.findIndex(item => item[prop] === value[prop]) === index;

// Usage:
const uniqueItems = items.filter(onlyUniqueProperty('key'));
```

If we want to support both JS and Immutable.js objects, small update:

```
const getProp = (obj, prop) => typeof obj.get === 'function' ? obj.get(prop) : obj[prop];

// Unique is only that item, if we find him in array on the same index.
const onlyUniqueProperty = prop => (value, index, self) =>
    self.findIndex(item => getProp(item, prop) === getProp(value, prop)) === index;

// Usage:
const uniqueItems = items.filter(onlyUniqueProperty('key'));
```